# Skimage simple imread of image return strange output

Tags: python, image, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm using the image reading of skimage module, and can't understand the output i get.
I'm trying to read a simple rgb image "lena.png" in the following way :

```
from skimage import io
im = io.imread('lena.png')
```

The output i get has the following properties :

```
In [49]: im
Out[49]: array(<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=512x512 at 0
x35FBD00>, dtype=object)

In [50]: im.shape
Out[50]: ()

In [51]: im.size
Out[51]: 1
```

Now i can't understand - why the shape of im isn't (512,512,3) ? 
This code is part of a bigger program i use and i get an error while some function try to figure out the number of color channels by accessing im.shape[2].

I'm adding a reference with the expected output :
see http://scipy-lectures.github.io/packages/scikit-image/ paragraph 3.2.2.2

```
>>> lena = data.lena()
>>> lena.shape
(512, 512, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error (`imread` returning an `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` class rather than a data array) often happens when you have older versions of the python imaging library `pillow` or worse still `PIL` installed. `pillow` is an updated "friendly" fork of `PIL` and definitely worth installing!

Try updating these packages; (depending on your python distribution)

```
# to uninstall PIL (if it's there, harmless if not)
$ pip uninstall PIL
# to install (or -U update) pillow
$ pip install -U pillow
```

and then try restarting your python shell and running the commands again.